# How could manage manifest file and package name of manifestProduct flavour

Tags: android

I have two product flavour both have different -2 Application id and different - 2 package name. I want to add two new activity and res (launcher activity and mani activity )in the second flavour. how could manage manifest file and package name of manifest?

Application structure

```
App
    src
        (1) main
            - java 
            - res
            - manifest
        (2) second
            - java 
            - res
            - manifest
```

Answer (score 0):

*First*, you need to create 2 different directory structure for both flavors:

```
App
    src
        main
            - java 
            - res
            - AndroidManifest.xml

        second
            - java 
            - res
            - AndroidManifest.xml
```

*Second*, add the specific Activities of **second** flavor to its AndroidManifest.xml. You need to clone the **main** AndroidManifest.xml first then add the Activities to it as your second AndroidManifest.xml

*Third*, add the flavor configuration to your app build.gradle like the following:

```
android {

  ...

  flavorDimensions "defaul"

  productFlavors {
  main {
    applictionId "com.your.application.main"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
  }

  second {
    applictionId "com.your.application.second"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
  }
  }
   ...
}
```

*Fourth*, add the **sourceSets** block for resource configuration in your app build.gradle:

```
android {
   ...

  sourceSets {

   // this is for second flavor
   second {
     manifest.srcFile 'src/second/AndroidManifest.xml'

     // this for resource, optional
     // it means that we need both of the resources from the folders
     res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/second/res']

     // for specific code, optional
     // it means that we use both of the java code from the folders.
     res.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/second/java']
   }

  }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you

What about package name of manifest file ?
Like 
      main package  - com.test.abc
      second package - com.test.xyz
how could this ?

Comment: you can try using manifestPlaceHolders in your app build.gradle : 
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      manifestPlaceholders = [packageName: "@string/package_name"]

   }

}


then in your AndroidManifest.xml, change the package name to:

<manifest xmlns ...
    package="${packageName}">

Comment: But I haven't try it yet. @string/package_name is come from your flavor resource string.

Comment: i try this @string/package_name is come from your flavour  resource string

"error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name."